# Are there any magnetic field while electron transfer in static electricity

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

I already know that the moving charge can generate magnetic field. But in this case, can magnetic field be generated.

Thank for answers

PS. This is just my curiosity.

Answer (score 2):

Any flow of electron signifies current flow. And any flow of current generates magnetic field.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of static electricity, the voltages may be significant but the currents generated are extremely small. Therefore any magnetic fields generated will be extremely small as well.